# отправка данных post запросов HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java

В некотором post запросе, который я отследил фидлером (Fiddler) имеется запись после всех заголовков (Host, connections, Referer и т.д) вида:

```
{"number":"10008","id":"25094"}
```

интересует каким образом отправить эти данные, и можно ли вообще отправлять если у меня протокол https, а не http, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Это самый обычный `POST` запрос, в теле запроса передается `JSON` с двумя полями.

```
HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

Тело пишете в выходной поток.

```
try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream())) {
    wr.write(postData);
}
```

`HTTP` или `HTTPS` у вас, не имеет никакого значения.