# Метод POST в Android 6.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, post

Начну с начала. Я начинающий разработчик под Android. Пишу приложение под **Android 6.0**. Потом, когда начал делать сервис понадобилось отсылать POST запрос серверу. Я нашёл один пример но он не подходит для Android 6.0.

```
public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "Hi"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

Кто знает, пожалуйста, напишите пример. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Подробнее опишите вашу задаяу.Что должен сервис делать?

Comment: И почему он не подходит?

Comment: @bukkojot, потому что https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client

Comment: Подробнее опишите вашу задачу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта библиотека от Apache объявлена как deprecated.
Вместо нее используйте `HttpUrlConnection`

[отправка данных post запросов HttpUrlConnection](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/631616/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-post-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-httpurlconnection/631629#631629)

Либо другую стороннюю библиотеку, `Retrofit` к примеру.

Comment: Т.е. уже собранное приложение, которое целится на АПИ 19, к примеру, на шестой версии просто перестанет работать?

Comment: Будет падать при обращении к классам пакета `org.apache.http`